# Open Office, htm и кириллица. Проблемы с отображением кириллицы

Tags: html, хостинг, ms-word, кириллица, open-office

Есть у меня сайт. Ничего особенного, просто несколько статических htm страниц для нескольких Open Source проектов.

Сайт довольно давний, лет 15 уже. Страницы были созданы в MS Word и выгружены в формате htm. Все работало, но недавно мне пришлось кое-то поменять на страницах.

Попробовал я поредактировать существующие htm страницы с помощью Open Office, дабы делом поддержать движение Open Source. И что же оказалось? Open Office без вопросов считал старые htm страницы, созданые в MS Word. В самом редакторе все отлично отредактировалось и показывалось как надо.

Но когда я закачал отредактированные страницы на сервер, то оказалось, что кириллица отображается бубновыми тузами со знаками вопросов поверх них. При том что латиница отображается нормально. Кроме того, напрочь съехала разметка и между каждыми строками Open Office вставил еще строку, выделенную серым. Вобщем ужосна.

Пришлось с позором все откатить, пойти на поклон к микрософту, и опять все сделать в MS Word.

Беглый осмотр кода htm показал, что Open Office налепил 100500 своих многомудрых тегов в код.

Вопрос:

1. Чего надо сделать, чтобы Open Office нормально отображал кириллицу в htm страницах?

PS. Браузер Хром. Хостинг бесплатный, бывший narod.ru, ныне это называется uCoz. Работаю на Windows-10-64 Home, соответственно Open Office у меня это порт Open Office под Windows. Версия Open Office 4.1.4.

Comment: Наверное нужны какие-то примеры.

Comment: Примеры чего? Кракозябров, отображающихся вместо кириллицы после редактирования htm страниц в Open Office? Я могу дать ссылку на сайт, но сейчас там все нормально, потому что сейчас на сайт залиты htm страницы, отредактированные в MS Word.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте в `head` добавить:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).